# Python - how to sort Priority Queue by second argument

Tags: python

Let's say, for example, that we have the following data that I want to insert
to a priority queue:
(0, 3, 5)
(1, 2, 7)
and I want to sort my priority queue by the second argument and then by the third.

How can I do that? beacuse, by default, priority queue sorts its elements by the first 
argument.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have to create your own `PriorityQueue` equivalent with the sorting logic you describe.

Comment: Why? I have Priority Queue library built in

Comment: @user3652239 according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) built-in PriorityQuere does not support custom ordering

Comment: Because `PriorityQueue`, as you point out, sorts by the first argument, and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) indicate no way to change that.

Comment: @user3652239 You can do it like I have shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23736162/1903116)

Answer (score 4):

The [implementation of `Queue.PriorityQueue`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/queue.py) relies on [`heappush()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappush), which doesn't provide a way to handle custom sorting.

You could subclass `PriorityQueue` and use a little hack to make this work without breaking functionnality:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

class CustomPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def _put(self, item):
        return super()._put((self._get_priority(item), item))

    def _get(self):
        return super()._get()[1]


    def _get_priority(self, item):
        return item[1]
```

Test run:

```
>>> q = CustomPriorityQueue(100)
>>> q.put((2, 3, 5))
>>> q.put((2, 5, 5))
>>> q.put((2, 1, 5))
>>> q.put((2, 2, 5))
>>> q.get()
(2, 1, 5)
>>> q.get()
(2, 2, 5)
>>> q.get()
(2, 3, 5)
>>> q.get()
(2, 5, 5)
```

(Please note that this is python3 code)

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation for Queue.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/Queue.py)

There actually a PriorityQueue that automatically sort the elements in queue, but usually the elements are tuple structure (priority number, data)

I wrote some sample code here, it Q._pop() the tuple with smallest priority number:

```
import Queue

q = Queue.PriorityQueue()

print type(q)
print(q.queue)
q._put((4,'f'))
q._put((1,'c'))
q._put((5, 'a'))
q._put((10, 'b'))
q._put((6, 'd'))
print(q.queue)
q._get()
print(q.queue)
q._put((2,'f'))
print(q.queue)
```

The output is:

```
<type 'instance'>
[]
[(1, 'c'), (4, 'f'), (5, 'a'), (10, 'b'), (6, 'd')]
[(4, 'f'), (6, 'd'), (5, 'a'), (10, 'b')]
[(2, 'f'), (4, 'f'), (5, 'a'), (10, 'b'), (6, 'd')]
```

One thing I notice is that for the first time we print the q.queue, before we do any _get(), it doesn't show ordered queue, but once we call _get(), it always gives ordered queue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) it appears that priority queue does not support custom ordering. 
A basic work around would be to create a wrapper object around your tuples and set the custom ordering in there

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self[1] == other[1]:
            return cmp(self.source, other.source)
        else:
            return cmp(self[1], other[1])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.source[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.source)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.source.__repr__()
```

This is merely an example, and you should take care of edge cases where the other object is a tuple, a list, an empty tuple and a tuple with one element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Wrapper class only with the `__ls__` method:

```
class MyObj:
  def __init__(self, key=None, data=None):
    self.key = key
    self.data = data

class Wrapper:
  def __init__(self, obj):
    self.obj = obj

  def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.obj.key < other.obj.key
```

And then add the object like this:

```
p = PriorityQueue()
p.put(Wrapper(MyObj(key=(3,5), data=(2,3,5))))
value = p.get().obj.data
```

To be noted that this works will all the sortedcontainers in Python. You can also obtain a maxheap by changing `return self.obj.key < other.obj.key` to `return self.obj.key > other.obj.key`!

Comment: To obtain max heap can we use __gt__? If yes what will be the condition? I have tried with some scenarios but the result was vague.